# How can I prevent nodes, that are set with automove to get moved by layouter?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have a cytoscape graph with these extensions:

- [Automove](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-automove)
- [Expand-Collapse](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-expand-collapse)

In my graph I have normal nodes with smaller nodes beside them (here in yellow). These smaller nodes are set with automove to move along with their linked node.

[image]

This happens with this function:

```js
private addCircle(nodeId: string, circleText: string): void {
        var parentNode = this.graph.getElementById(nodeId)
        if (parentNode.data('isCircle') || parentNode.data('circleId')) return

        var px = parentNode.position('x') + 10
        var py = parentNode.position('y') - 10

        var circleId = (this.graph.nodes().size() + 1).toString()
        parentNode.data('circleId', circleId)
        this.graph
            .add({
                group: 'nodes',
                data: { id: circleId, name: circleText },
                position: { x: px, y: py },
                classes: 'XorGroup_' + circleText,
            })
            .unselectify()
            .ungrabify()

        this.graph.automove({
            nodesMatching: this.graph.getElementById(circleId),
            reposition: 'drag',
            dragWith: parentNode,
        })
    }
```

If I move the "parent" its works totally fine, but if I use the collapse function of the "Expand-Collapse" extension, the nodes are seperated from their "parent" and get placed in the upper left corner.
This collapse event is used on totally different nodes.

[image]

I tried to use this function:

```js
cy.nodes().on("expandcollapse.aftercollapse", function(event) { var node = this; ... })
```

Unfortunatelly it fires before the layout is calculated by the "Expand-Collapse" extension.

Does anybody have an idea how to manage, that the smaller nodes are ALWAYS on the same relative position to their "parent"?